# jmeter thread group vs Constant Throughput Timer

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am conducting a performance test (TPS) using jmeter.

I am requesting about 10,000 TPS, but the following two results are different.
(Position that 10,000 TPS responds normally)

1. 1000 thread x 600 target throughput(in samples per minute)
2. 100 thread x 6000 target throughput(in samples per minute)

I think the two results should be the same, but why is the response time delayed as the thread increases?

Answer (score 1):

`I think the two results should be the same` - why they would be the same?

Let's imagine your system has fixed response time of 1 second, in that case:

1. With 1000 threads you will get 1000 requests per second and you can limit the throughput to 10 requests per second using the Constant Throughput Timer
2. With 100 threads you will get 100 requests per second, no limiting is required

And what if response time is 2 seconds?

1. With 1000 threads you will get 500 requests per second
2. With 100 threads you will get 50 requests per second

Constant Throughput Timer:

- acts precise enough on "minute" scale, if your test lasts less than minute it might not apply the throughput
- can only **pause** the threads to **limit** the throughput (requests per minute) to the desired value. If current number of threads is not enough in order to conduct the required load - the time won't have any effect.

If you want to send requests at the rate of 10000 TPS it worth considering going for the [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin) and [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) combination connected via the [Feedback Function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/#Use-With-Throughput-Shaping-Timer-Feedback-Function) in this case JMeter will be able to kick off extra threads if current number is not sufficient.

But also be informed that:

1. JMeter should be able to start as many threads as needed to send 10000 TPS so make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) or even consider going for [Distributed Testing Mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.html)
2. Application needs to be able to handle the load and respond fast enough, JMeter waits for the previous response before starting the new request so if application is able to serve i.e. 5000 requests per second only you won't be able to reach 10000 by any means

Comment: I mean...
When setting the 100thread 18000 throughput timer, about 30,000 TPS comes out.

If this is set to the 1800 throughput timer of 1000thread, it will be reduced to 20,000 TPS level.

Is there a difference between the two?